# Windows 10 - Surface Pro 5 missing Sleep option

Tags: windows-10, sleep, microsoft-surface-pro

I cannot get my Surface Pro 5 to sleep. It only knows how to hibernate.

Steps taken:

1. Restarted
2. Let Windows Update run
3. Change power plan settings

[image]

4. Change advanced power plan settings

[image]

5. Run the troubleshooter (`Control Panel > Update and Security > Troubleshoot > Power`)

[image]

6. Enabled "Sleep" option from Group Policy Editor, under `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer`

[image]

7. Check the available power states from PowerShell

[image]

8. Attempted to refer to official help content ("Why can't I change some settings" link from #3). This link immediately redirects to the Microsoft website's homepage (i.e. is a dead link).

[image]

9. Attempted to contact Microsoft support thru the link on their homepage

[image]

Furthermore, every time I turn my tablet back on, the wifi is broken and requires manually disabling and re-enabling (otherwise it shows connected to the previous network indefinitely).

It has always been like this since I received it as a warranty replacement to my Surface Pro 4, in early 2020 directly from a Microsoft store.

Comment: The reason you are being told your system is being managed by a policies is due to the fact you have Enabled the group policies.  As for the reason the sleep option is missing, there simply isn't enough information, to determine that.

Comment: I would be inclined to call Microsoft on the phone and ask to either suggest a known repair or have it replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Surfaces are [supposed](https://www.windowscentral.com/connected-standby-and-why-its-important-surface-pro-3) to rely on Connected/Modern Standby.

As reported [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/w10-i7-surface-book-sleep-disappeared-from/d24b3dd5-2c89-4525-8b05-b564ef2da538?page=2), if it gets [disabled](https://borncity.com/win/2020/11/26/windows-10-v2004-cant-deactivate-modern-standby/) for some reason you loose all the standby capabilities.